# When to multiplex related media streams into one RTP connection?

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0

I'm working on an eyetracker, an scientific embedded device seperately filming the eyeballs and what's in front of the head. We seek to provide these three video feeds as well as some additional data calculated from them (gaze point and others) over plain RTP. (No RTSP or RTCP.)

## Question:

From the perspective of the RTP specification, is it proper to multiplex these feeds into one RTP connection, or should they be provided via different RTP streams?

The RTP specification RFC 3550 has a [chapter on RTP multiplexing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#section-5.2), but I'm not entirely sure what it means in our case.

I don't know what their definition of *seperate* as in *seperate media streams* is. In our case, the video feeds and the metadata are all in sync, but generated by different sensors (different cameras in case of the video feeds, or calculated based on the video feeds in case of the metadata) mounted on the same assembly.

The RFC talks about one usage of the same SSRC as a source of problem in RTP multiplexing. So to avoid that we'd just need to make sure to use different SSRCs, I guess?

I'd lean towards multiplexing the media channels into one RTP stream and would love get feedback from some RTP experts wether that's bad in this particular use case.

## RTP spec extract (RFC 3550)

```
5.2 Multiplexing RTP Sessions

   For efficient protocol processing, the number of multiplexing points
   should be minimized, as described in the integrated layer processing
   design principle [10].  In RTP, multiplexing is provided by the
   destination transport address (network address and port number) which
   is different for each RTP session.  For example, in a teleconference
   composed of audio and video media encoded separately, each medium
   SHOULD be carried in a separate RTP session with its own destination
   transport address.

   Separate audio and video streams SHOULD NOT be carried in a single
   RTP session and demultiplexed based on the payload type or SSRC
   fields.  Interleaving packets with different RTP media types but
   using the same SSRC would introduce several problems:

   1. If, say, two audio streams shared the same RTP session and the
      same SSRC value, and one were to change encodings and thus acquire
      a different RTP payload type, there would be no general way of
      identifying which stream had changed encodings.

   2. An SSRC is defined to identify a single timing and sequence number
      space.  Interleaving multiple payload types would require
      different timing spaces if the media clock rates differ and would
      require different sequence number spaces to tell which payload
      type suffered packet loss.

   3. The RTCP sender and receiver reports (see Section 6.4) can only
      describe one timing and sequence number space per SSRC and do not
      carry a payload type field.

   4. An RTP mixer would not be able to combine interleaved streams of
      incompatible media into one stream.

   5. Carrying multiple media in one RTP session precludes: the use of
      different network paths or network resource allocations if
      appropriate; reception of a subset of the media if desired, for
      example just audio if video would exceed the available bandwidth;
      and receiver implementations that use separate processes for the
      different media, whereas using separate RTP sessions permits
      either single- or multiple-process implementations.

   Using a different SSRC for each medium but sending them in the same
   RTP session would avoid the first three problems but not the last
   two.

   On the other hand, multiplexing multiple related sources of the same
   medium in one RTP session using different SSRC values is the norm for
   multicast sessions.  The problems listed above don't apply: an RTP
   mixer can combine multiple audio sources, for example, and the same
   treatment is applicable for all of them.  It may also be appropriate
   to multiplex streams of the same medium using different SSRC values
   in other scenarios where the last two problems do not apply.
```

Answer (score 1):

> We seek to provide these three video feeds as well as some additional
> data calculated

So you have 4 streams : 3 videos and one metadata streams and they need to be synchronized as far as i understand.

> From the perspective of the RTP specification, is it proper to
> multiplex these feeds into one RTP connection, or should they be
> provided via different RTP streams?

I would recommend to use 4 RTP streams and use the Sender Report (SR) from RTCP to synchronize them, you can see [RTP timestamp in data packets vs RTCP SR packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72196075/rtp-timestamp-in-data-packets-vs-rtcp-sr-packets) for more informations.

There is no absolute need for RTCP especially if you have only one stream or not interested in quality of service but with multiple streams that need to be synchronized, it is really useful.